# Encoded ID in URL path on IIS with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, urlencode

We have an Id that could look something like this:

```
WIUHyUT/Evg=/
```

That we would like to use in the path or an url:

```
http://localhost/freelancers/WIUHyUT/Evg=/Brigitte
```

This obviously does not work, so we used HttpUtility.UrlEncode() and get

```
http://localhost/freelancers/WIUHyUT%2fEvg%3d/Brigitte
```

But this still does not work.
What would be a good approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually decided to encode the whole thing into HEX first:

```
    public static string GetBytesToString(byte[] value)
    {
        SoapHexBinary shb = new SoapHexBinary(value);
        return shb.ToString();
    }
```

With this we then just had HEX codes in the url. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the url string back, you have to decode it.
Also, you should use any slashes after encoded params, use ampersand instead to join them.

Comment: Yes, decoding is ok, but the url does not work in the first place.

Comment: it should look like http://localhost/freelancers/id=WIUHyUT%2fEvg%3d&name=Brigitte or you better encode whole "WIUHyUT/Evg=/Brigitte" part